# How to write $E(X|A)=\frac{E(X\mathbf{1_A})}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$ in form of conditional density

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

**Q1**

I've seen most of the conditional expectation taking the form $E(X|Y=y)$, but recently just come across $E(X|A)$ a lot from stochastic text, where $A$ could be explicitly involved r.v $X$ or not

By definition:

$$E(X|A)=\frac{E(X\mathbf{1_A})}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$$

If the event $A$ related to r.v $X$, I can rewrite in the form as intergral of $x\times $*conditional density*  $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\frac{f(x)\mathbf{1_A}}{\mathbb{P}(A)}dx$$ the conditional density can be think of as $$\frac{f(x)\mathbf{1_A}}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$$ and this makes a connection with introductory level definition.

Now, if the event $A$ involves another r.v $Y$, the formula becomes

$$E(X|A)=\frac{E(X\mathbf{1_{\{Y\in A\}}})}{\mathbb{P}(A)}=\frac{\int_A\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf(x,y)dxdy}{\int_A\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)dxdy}$$ I am trying to turn this into a conditonal density form, similar to my previous example, making some connection with introductory level, but I don't know how to figure this out.

**Q2**

Does it make sense to talk about the conditional expectation of an event? Simply $E(X\in A|Y\in B)$, I mainly encounter conditional expectations of random variables.

Sincerely looking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1, if $(X, Y)$ is jointly continuous with the joint PDF $f(x, y)$, and if $A$ is $\sigma(X,Y)$-measurable such that it is of the form $A = \{(X, Y) \in B\}$ for some Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then LOTUS tells that

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[u(X) \mid A]
&= \frac{\mathbf{E}[u(X) \mathbf{1}_{B}(X, Y)]}{\mathbf{P}((X, Y) \in B)} \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} u(x) \left( \frac{1}{\mathbf{P}((X, Y) \in B)} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_{B}(x, y) f(x, y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right) \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

From this, we get

$$ f_{X \mid \{(X,Y) \in B\}}(x) = \frac{1}{\mathbf{P}((X, Y) \in B)} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_{B}(x, y) f(x, y) \, \mathrm{d}y. $$

Of course, if $A$ depends only on $X$ so that $A = \{ X \in C \}$ for some Borel subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}$, then the above formula reduces to

$$ f_{X\mid \{X \in C\}} (x) = \frac{\mathbf{1}_{C}(x)}{\mathbf{P}(X \in C)} f_X(x). $$

(Note that you can't simply put the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_A$ here; it is not even a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ in general.)

For Q2, it doesn't make sense to talk about the (conditional) expectation of an event, but you can talk about that of an indicator function:

$$ \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{1}_A \mid B] \bbox[color:#A0A0A0;]{=\mathbf{P}(A \mid B)}. $$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Why does my $\mathbf{1_A}(x)$ is not measurable? and I don't see much difference with that $\mathbf{1_C}(x)$ related density form.

Comment: @LJNG, If the ambient probability space is denoted by $\Omega$, then $A$ is a (measurable) subset of $\Omega$ and not of $\mathbb{R}$. So, $\mathbf{1}_A$ is not even a function on $\mathbb{R}$ (but rather on $\Omega$).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's true. Is that make sense $E(X|A)$ form referring to some Borel $A$, my $\mathbf{1_A}$ should be $\mathbf{1_{\{X\in A\}}}$

Answer (score 1):

To answer Q2 first: the most basic definition of conditional probability (i.e. essentially conditional expectation) is simply conditioning on an event: $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$. How does this relate to conditional expectations? We simply write $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B) = \mathbb{E}[{1_{A \mid B}}]$, where $1: \Omega \to \{ 0, 1 \}$ is the indicator function. In your case, $\{ Y \in B \}$ is simply an event, so we can naturally deal with it in this way.

Q1: This is a more special case, where we assume $X$ and $Y$ have well-defined densities (i.e. they are continuous). Now your statements are true, but I am not sure if trying to write the conditional density in terms of $Y$ makes sense; the event $A$ is simply $\{ Y \in B \}$, which either occurs or not, and you do not care about the exact value of $Y$. If it were something else like $\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]$ (this is more abstractly defined, but intuitively it can be thought of "$\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y = y]$"), then it would make sense to have a conditional density $f_{X \mid Y}(x, y)$ which depends on the values $X$ and $Y$ take.